# How can I make the transparent parts of a material totally invisible?

Tags: shaders, transparency, image

I have a material which is just a PNG with alpha, plugged into a Principled BSDF node. I've set the Viewport Display Blend Mode to Alpha Clip, and the transparent parts are transparent, but not *totally invisible*.

I've tried turning the Transmission value to 1, and trying other Blend Modes than Alpha Clip, but nothing seems to work.

[image: Screenshot of Blender]

I've moved the transparent texture over to the side to show that the surface not covered by it reflects the grain of the metal behind, but the surface covered by it does not.

Is there a setting I'm missing? Here's my node setup, it's very simple:

[image: Screenshot of Blender shader nodes]

Comment: Did you add a png file or did you unwrap the object and applied the png as a material?